# Android loading different contents in the same screen but different activities

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout, android-widget

i am new to Android and i am facing a problem in calling different activities from the same screen with same user interface. 
Actually i want to implement d functionality of a tab activity but instead of tabs i am providing buttons and the buttons should act like tabs.
I am unable to do that. I am going wrong some where. 
Can anyone help me please..... 
HomeScreen class is:

```
public class HomeScreen extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    public Integer[] images = { R.raw.mobile, R.raw.note_books, R.raw.ac,
            R.raw.drivers, R.raw.camera, R.raw.home_theaters, R.raw.pda,
            R.raw.tv, R.raw.washing_machines, R.raw.scanners };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid);
        GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridV);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        gv.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(images, inflater));
        gv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        if (StaticUtils.scheckStatus){
            parseData();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent contents = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, Cat.class);
        contents.putExtra("homescreen", arg2);
        startActivity(contents);
    }
```

Cat.class is this:

```
class Cat extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private Button mBtnContents, mBtnBrand, mBtnCategory, mBtnBack;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle si){
        super.onCreate(si);
        setContentView(R.layout.gridtab);
        int i = getIntent().getIntExtra("homescreen", 0);
        mBtnContents=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContents);
        mBtnContents.setOnClickListener(this);

        mBtnBrand=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBrand);
        mBtnBrand.setOnClickListener(this);

        mBtnCategory=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCategory);
        mBtnCategory.setOnClickListener(this);

        mBtnBack=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        mBtnBack.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==mBtnContents){
            int i = getIntent().getIntExtra("homescreen", 0);
            Intent in=new Intent(Cat.this, Pc.class);
            in.putExtra("homescreen", i);
            startActivity(in);
        } else if(v==mBtnBrand){
            startActivity(new Intent(Cat.this, Sd.class));
        } else if(v==mBtnCategory){
            startActivity(new Intent(Cat.this, Sbc.class));
        } else if(v==mBtnBack){
            startActivity(new Intent(Cat.this, Hs.class));
        }

    }
}
```

When i click on contents button its displaying the details but when i click on the other buttons its not showing anythng

Comment: I am done with designing part but the functionality is not working

Comment: So what's exactly the problem you are facing?

Comment: Tq for the response. Here is my problem. When i click on the button it's starting the other activity. The other activity also has the same buttons when i click on the buttons there they are not working properly.

Comment: Try to explain the problem more detailed, post some code, You can edit your question for this. With the info you've already provided I can't imagine what do you want to achieve and what's wrong

Comment: Hmm, your code seems ok. Are you sure your `Sd`, `Sbc` and `Hs` activities don't receive an intent? If there's `finish()` in `onCreate` or `onStart` in these activities, you won't see them starting at all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "v==mBtnContents" use "v.equals(mBtnContents)" because View is an object.